# Parallax images overflowing even after CSS is overflow hidden

Tags: css, overflow, parallax

I have a project where I am using parallax effect. My code is exactly like this in that project:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){

var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
$('.flying-man').css({'transform':'translateY( -'+ ( wScroll- $('.flying-man').offset().top/1.2 )/150+'%)'});
});
```

```css
#fun2 {
  margin-top: 8%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.space-back {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgyaY.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.flying-man {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMAGK.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom left;
  background-size: 70%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /*background-color: rgba(2,2,2,0.5);*/
}
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="fun2">
  <div class="space">
    <div class="space-back"></div>
    <div class="flying-man"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="speakers2">
</section>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/SIrNqv8h6QGKDuNoLGA4iret+kyesCkHGzVUUV0shc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

All I want is the second image the one having class `.flying-man` to be contained in the section and not overflow. I have a script that translate it from y axis (downward to upward on scroll).

You can see the problem in this image.

[image]

Comment: Please include the script you're using - it's hard to debug unless we can run your code ourselves!

Comment: added the images and js whats the problem now ? pls help

Comment: When you set `display: absolute` (in CSS), you take the element out of the normal document flow. An absolute element is no longer constrained by its parent, but by the whole page. I.e. If you don't use `display: absolute` or you make it work with more JavaScript, then you should be on your way to getting what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add

```
#fun2 {
  margin-top: 8%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;     /* <<< this */
}
```

otherwise `overflow: hidden` will have no effect